# x-forwarded-for header missing in http request while it going through AWS LoadBalancer to spring boot application

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, tomcat, aws-application-load-balancer, x-forwarded-for

I have spring boot application. Running this spring boot application behind proxy i.e AWS Loadbalancer.

In that there is one endpoint

```
@GetMapping(value = "/test", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Object getTestResponse(@RequestHeader("id") String id, @RequestHeader(required = true, value = "x-forwarded-for") String clientIpAddress,) throws IOException {
//Other logic goes here
        
}
```

Application running without any error in aws cloud.

If I try to access the endpoint "\test" with required request payload and header.

`curl -v -H 'id:12345678' -H 'x-forwarded-for:192.168.0.2' http://example.com/context/services/test`

I am getting the x-forwarded-for missing error, even  though it passed while I am calling the endpoint.

> .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingRequestHeaderException: **Required request header 'x-forwarded-for' for method parameter type String is not present**

After the research, I have done changes in spring boot application and AWS configuration

1. Spring boot application change

   To receive this x-forwarded-for header from ALB to servlet(Tomcat) container, Added below property in application.yml

   ```
   server:
   ```

   ```
    forward-headers-strategy: NATIVE
   ```

   As metioned spring boot documentation - [Doc link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.webserver.use-behind-a-proxy-server)
2. AWS Load Balancer

   There is a X-Forwarded-For header atrribute in load balancer. I change it value to Preserve . Because in my cause I need to preserve the x-forwarded-for header from client request.

   [AWS Document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/x-forwarded-headers.html) for your reference regarding X-Forwarded-For header atrribute values. Such as Append, Preserve, Remove.

I don't know what I am missing here, after above change also I am getting `x-forwarded-for header missing error in spring boot application log`

Kindly check and help me to solve this issue , Feel free to share your valuable thoughts.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you still having this issue? For debugging purposes try removing the @RequestHeader requirement and instead pull the headers out of the HttpServletRequest object method getHeaders. Use "X-Forwarded-For". Its not suppose to be case sensitive but use that specific case "X-Forwarded-For" not "x-forwarded-for" and see what happens.  Also remove any special AWS config you added because that header is added automatically. You dont need to add it to your curl. You should just curl and confirm the header is present. The ELB adds it not your client so remove it from the CURL command.